# React Native project-- How to create ios and android folders in reactnative app

Tags: react-native

I am working on react native expo project and I have no knowledge regarding how to create iOS and android folders within expo project.so please help me regarding how to create iOS and android folders and at last how to make final build.

Comment: Hello @MadhuriP, I think your question is about how to get the final APK or IPA right?

Comment: No, I am creating a new project. In the internal project folder I am unable to find the ios and android folder when I create new project.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot have android and ios folders in an expo project. Expo is a wrapper of React Native. If you need a native component or native code access. You need to `eject` from expo.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have android and ios folders in an expo project, if you want to edit native code you need to build with RN CLI and leave expo, or change to Bare workflow

https://docs.expo.dev/introduction/managed-vs-bare/